# How can I exclude warning messages when using PHP DomDocument?

Tags: php

I'm trying to use the DomDocument class to load and analyse an HTML fragment (doesn't include the `<html>` and `<body>` tags). There is a lot of garbage left over from MS-Word when it was converted into HTML, so I'm getting warning messages such as `DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag o:p invalid in Entity, line: 69 ddtest.d8.drush.inc:68`.
Here is the relevant code:

```
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    //load the html into the object
    $dom->loadHTML($row->body_value);
```

I've tried to get rid of the warning messages by using this:

```
    $dom = new DOMDocument;

    //load the html into the object
    $dom->loadHTML($row->body_value, LIBXML_NOWARNING);
```

But it has no effect, the warning messages are still displayed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: RTFM? http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php  `While malformed HTML should load successfully, this function may generate E_WARNING errors when it encounters bad markup. libxml's error handling functions may be used to handle these errors.`

Comment: It might be RTFM if I had not got what I was trying to do from from http://php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the error handling of `libxml` like this perhaps:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors( true );

$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->validateOnParse = false;
$dom->standalone=true;
$dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
$dom->substituteEntities=true;
$dom->recover=true;
$dom->formatOutput=false;
$dom->loadHTML( $row->body_value );

libxml_clear_errors();
```